# Is it wrong to use "if IE" conditional comment to control what content is displayed?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a simple HTML login form in which I only want to display it to users with Internet Explorer (as per existing design, obviously not by choice) and display an error message when accessed by any other browser.

My question is, how wrong is it to use the `<!--[if IE]>` tag in the body to determine what content to show, if at all? Are there any drawbacks to using this?

**login.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>

  <!--[if IE]>
    <form>
      ...
    </form>
  <![endif]-->

  <![if !IE]>
    This site can only be accessed via Internet Explorer
  <![endif]-->

</body>
</html>
```

I am well aware I can use JavaScript, CSS or Server-side things to perform this, but I want to change the code and design as minimally as possible and actually quite curious as to the drawbacks of the above method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to MSDN, conditional comments are not supported in standards mode as of IE 10.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

That said, if you are supporting the browsers you need by using them go for it.  But don't be surprised if they get phased out going forward.

Also, your syntax is wrong on the not IE comment.  Should be two comments so other browsers handle it correctly.

```
<!--[if !IE]-->
    This site can only be accessed via Internet Explorer
<!--[endif]-->
```

Comment: Actually, with the edits you suggested it doesn't work in Chrome (v24), the code I have does work although I cannot explain it as your syntax obviously looks more correct.

Comment: And that is fine regarding IE10, it'll be a long time before it's viewed in that browser.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you attempt to do browser detection you run the risk of false positives in your application. Browser detection can come in many forms:

- Conditional comments
- User Agent sniffing
- Non-standard API tests

You're better off using **Feature Detection** to identify what your browser does/doesn't support and provide alternatives. [Here's a good write up on both subjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh475813.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion as long as:

1. You are using valid html (css & js)
2. It works correctly across all the browsers you choose to support

Then there is no reason not to.

Alot about html and css comes down to personal preference as long as you are achieving the above then go for it.

Comment: Thanks mate, that is the same mindset that I run with too, but just wanted to get some opinions on it. Appreciate the feedback.

Comment: @Markasoftware why the minus one then? I said, as long as he is using VALID html...read my post properly before jumping the gun

Comment: @shenku Internet explorer 10 no longer supports conditional comments and they will not work in it. If you try to use them IE10 will treat them as normal comments and will not care what is in them. If they do not work, they should not be used. See nickles80's answer.

Comment: @Markasoftware Thanks for the input and I understand what you're saying, but for enterprise IE10 is still unfortunately bleeding edge and for this particular environment the comments will work fine for a lot more years.

Comment: @Matt IE10 is the current version of IE, not bleeding edge. It has about half the market share of safari, and considering it has doubled in the last month we can expect this single version of internet explorer to overtake all versions of apple's browser within 1 or 2 months, not years. At the current it has approximately 3% worldwide usage, and with 2.1 billion internet users worldwide that makes more than 60 million users of IE10. But then again, it's your choice if you want to make your website inaccessible to 60 million people. Also, it is bad to use deprecated features.

Comment: @markasoftware "...for enterprise IE10 is still unfortunately bleeding edge...". As stated, I understand what you're saying but for this specific implementation, being an internal website, I don't think those 60 million people will be affected. And this company in particular is looking at 4+ years at least before IE10 will be utilized. I completely agree with you though that the most current standards should always be adhered to, bit of a special case here though.